# How to set maximum width and width to fit content for columns in an HTML/CSS table

Tags: html, css

I have a simple HTML/CSS code that contains a container with two extendable slots. The handler in the middle can change how much space content in each slot takes. In the first slot, there is a table with fixed columns, automatic columns, and limited columns.

Here's the behavior I want to achieve:

1. For all columns, if the content does not fit within the column width, it should be truncated with an ellipsis and not wrap to the next line.
2. Fixed columns have a constant width.
3. Automatic columns should adjust their width based on the slot's width.
4. Limited columns should have a maximum width. In case when the content of a limited column is smaller than the maximum width, it should have the width of its content. They do not change their size based on the slot’s width: they are similar to the fixed columns but with the maximum width limit and ability being as small as their content is.

The current code doesn't achieve the desired behavior for the limited columns. How can I modify the code to make the limited columns have the smallest possible size to fit the content but no larger than the maximum width?

```js
const handler = document.querySelector(".handler");
const leftSlot = document.querySelector(".left-slot");
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

let startX;
let initialWidth;

handler.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
  startX = e.clientX;
  initialWidth = leftSlot.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
  document.addEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
});

function onMouseMove(e) {
  const w = container.clientWidth;
  const dx = 100 * (e.clientX - startX) / w;
  leftSlot.style.width = `${initialWidth / w * 100 + dx}%`;
}

function onMouseUp() {
  document.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
  document.removeEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.left-slot {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

.right-slot {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
}

.handler {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  cursor: col-resize;
}


/* Table styles */

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.fixed-1,
.fixed-2,
.fixed-3 {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.auto {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  min-width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.limited {
  width: 1px;
  max-width: 100px;
  background-color: lightsalmon;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-slot">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="fixed-1">Fixed 1</td>
        <td class="fixed-2">Fixed 2</td>
        <td class="auto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam luctus odio sit amet nisi egestas, tincidunt auctor erat posuere. Duis varius id nibh id lobortis. </td>
        <td class="fixed-3">Fixed 3</td>
        <td class="limited">Limited 1</td>
        <td class="limited">Limited 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="fixed-1">Fixed 1 even if longer </td>
        <td class="fixed-2">Fixed 2</td>
        <td class="auto">-Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </td>
        <td class="fixed-3">Fixed 3</td>
        <td class="limited">Limited 1 longer</td>
        <td class="limited">Short</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="handler"></div>
  <div class="right-slot">
    <div>Some content here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know how to achieve the desired behaviour with HTML table and basic CSS, however, I found out how to do it using the grid layout. Basically, I set the max-width for `.limited` class and then use `minmax(min-content, max-content)` for such columns. For the automatic column I have set `minmax(0px, auto)` because for some reason they are not shrinked until 0px when it is just `auto`.

```js
const handler = document.querySelector(".handler");
const leftSlot = document.querySelector(".left-slot");
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

let startX;
let initialWidth;

handler.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
  startX = e.clientX;
  initialWidth = leftSlot.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  document.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
  document.addEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
});

function onMouseMove(e) {
  const w = container.clientWidth;
  const dx = 100 * (e.clientX - startX) / w;
  leftSlot.style.width = `${initialWidth / w * 100 + dx}%`;
}

function onMouseUp() {
  document.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
  document.removeEventListener("mouseup", onMouseUp);
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.left-slot {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

.right-slot {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 10px;
}

.handler {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  cursor: col-resize;
}


/* Grid container styles */

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px minmax(0px, auto) 100px minmax(min-content, max-content) minmax(min-content, max-content);
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.grid-container > div {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border: 0.5px solid black;
}

.fixed-1,
.fixed-2,
.fixed-3 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.auto {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  text-overflow: clip !important;
}

.limited {
  background-color: lightsalmon;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-slot">
    <div class="grid-container">
      <!-- First row -->
      <div class="fixed-1">Fixed 1</div>
      <div class="fixed-2">Fixed 2</div>
      <div class="auto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam luctus odio sit amet nisi egestas, tincidunt auctor erat posuere. Duis varius id nibh id lobortis.</div>
      <div class="fixed-3">Fixed 3</div>
      <div class="limited">Limited 1</div>
      <div class="limited">Limited 2</div>
      <!-- Second row -->
      <div class="fixed-1">Fixed 1 even if longer</div>
      <div class="fixed-2">Fixed 2</div>
      <div class="auto">-Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
      <div class="fixed-3">Fixed 3</div>
      <div class="limited">Limited 1 longer</div>
      <div class="limited">Short</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="handler"></div>
  <div class="right-slot">
    <div>Some content here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```